# Trouble with loss function tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function

I am trying to train a u-net network with binary targets. The usual Binary Cross Entropy loss does not perform well, since the lables are very imbalanced (many more 0 pixels than 1s). So I want to punish false negatives more. But tensorflow doesn't have a ready-made weighted binary cross entropy. Since I didn't want to write a loss from scratch, I'm trying to use tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits. to be able to easily feed the loss to model.compile function, I'm writing this wrapper:

```
def loss_wrapper(y,x):
   x = tf.cast(x,'float32')
   loss = tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(y,x,pos_weight=10)
   return loss
```

However, regardless of casting x to float, I'm still getting the error:

```
TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type int32 of argument 'x'.
```

when the tf loss is called. Can someone explain what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` represents your predictions. It probably already has the type `float32`. I think you need to cast `y`, which is presumably your labels. So:

```
loss = tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(tf.cast(y, dtype=tf.float32),x,pos_weight=10)
```

Comment: ok, you're right. That's embarassing :D Thanks